# What is the winforms control that Visual Studio uses as a properties editor?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

What is the winforms control that Visual Studio uses as a properties editor? It is a two column table with the names on the left side and the editible value on the right side.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx).